# how to generate load using loadUI?

Tags: performance, testing, load-testing, loadui

I want to generate load test using soapui+loadui integrated test case for generating load on our instance of tomcat but when i increase request rate to 200 to 500 or 800 at that time most of the request will be discarded

what was the problem ?
i am using following version 
loadui 2.0
soapui 4.5

help me out to create test case that generate more then 3000 req/sec.

Answer (score 0):

If requests are discarded, that means that at least 100 (default value which can be changed) requests are running (the server hasn't completed them yet).

- If no requests are completed at all, loadUI cannot access your server.
- If some requests are completed, your server is simply too slow to handle the load.

Read more about this [here](http://loadui.org/Runners/running-your-tests.html#1-flowchart).

My advice is to start out at a very low rate, and connect a TableLog to the soapUI Runner for easier debugging.